# MySQL via PHP: not returning certain rows and I cannot figure out why

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me insane. I have an `Items` table (PK `item_id`). Each item belongs to a category and so one of the fields of the table is `category_id`. Here is the simplified SQL I am using to debug this:

`SELECT * FROM Items WHERE category_id = '?'`

I am replacing ? with the category ID's manually for debugging purposes, for now. There are 5 items in the table with id's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Now here is where it gets weird.

- Item 1's category is 17. In phpMyAdmin the above query using 17 as the parameter returns Item 1. PHP does not.
- PHP returns all of the other items fine when using their categories: 15, 13, 10, and 14.
- If I alter Item 1 in the database to have a category ID of either 15, 13, 10, or 14 it still does **not** show up in the results within PHP.
- If I alter Item 1 in the database to have a different category ID, for example 4, it still does **not** show up in the results.
- If I alter any other item to have a category ID of 17, that item will *no longer show up* (both that item and Item 1 do not, i.e., there are no results).

So what is going on here? Item 1, and Item 1 only, will never show up no matter what, and other categories will not show up if given a category of 17 but show up otherwise? And it works in phpMyAdmin, but not PHP?

Here is the PHP code to test this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Items` WHERE `category_id` = '17'");

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $r['item_id'];
}
```

Here is `SHOW CREATE TABLE Items`:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Items` (
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `description` varchar(250) default NULL,
 `name` varchar(25) default NULL,
 `category_id` int(11) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`item_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
 KEY `FK_Items_Categories` (`category_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_Items_Categories` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`category_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And Categories:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Categories` (
 `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `parent_id` int(11) default NULL,
 `name` varchar(25) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`),
 KEY `FK_Categories_Categories` (`parent_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_Categories_Categories` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note: I did not create the database, so let me know if there is a problem with this.

Comment: Did you try query without quotations around category_id value? `\`category_id\` = 17`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Same result.

Comment: Can you post your database structure in more details please?

Comment: What happens with no WHERE clause? Please also give the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Items`.

Comment: With no WHERE clause, it echos every item "12345".

Comment: phpMyAdmin is written in PHP, as well, so the problem probably lies in your code.

Comment: @Basti, I have posted my code and don't see anything wrong with it. It is literally copy and pasted from text editor and every other category ID works when I simply change "17" to "15" (or any other category ID). If you see something wrong with it, let me know.

Comment: Do a `echo $r['category_id'];` without WHERE in mysql, please

Comment: Gabriel, Item 1 is returning "12" for it's category! That seems to be the problem. In the category table, the category of ID 17 has a parent category of ID 12. Will post `SHOW CREATE TABLE`...

Comment: @Logan Serman It might not be the part, you showed. Please help us to reproduce this scenario by providing the table structure including indexes and table engine, and any other relevant php code that you have to execute to produce this error. (minimum working example)

Comment: If item id `1` have category `12`, I think it is only a mysql misstake you have made.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, item 1's `category_id` shows up as 17, not 12. The 12 is coming from a Categories table, which stores a tree of categories `(item_id, parent_id, name)`. The `parent_id` of category 17 is 12. But why does a `SELECT *` on Items return 12 and not 17, when 17 is the value in the Items database?

Comment: Got some foreign key magic going? Did you use the phpmyadmin designer to create relations between those tables?

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE Categories`

Comment: So if I understand you correctly phpMyAdmin does actually show the wrong information. What version are you using. Try updating your phpMyAdmin to the latest version.

Comment: @Basti It is not phpMyAdmin issue. phpMyAdmin work as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about this. It doesnt get any simpler than `SELECT * FROM \`tableName\``. Also there are realy old phpMyAdmin installations out there. ;-)

Comment: @Basti he omitted a lot of mysql and PHP codes. And, with the code he posted, I'm surely this is a MYSQL issue.

Comment: Yeah maybe. I would nonetheless first try to update phpMyAdmin since it's a trivial task. Updating MySQL or even PHP is not! ;-) I'm still puzzled about the different results, considering that phpMyAdmin is written in PHP as well. The problem would have to be some kind of error that is only present in native mysql extension, not in PDO/mysqli.

Comment: I think it is an issue with MyISAM. I am working on converting to InnoDB, but I'm getting errno: 150, which apparently is a pain to fix. After I fix that I'll let you know what happens. What I don't understand is why every other item works, except Item 1.

Comment: @LoganSerman have you tried my last answer before convert all your db?

Comment: Yes, it does not work. Neither does InnoDB. The only thing that changes it the value in the Items table for the `category_id` field is now a clickable link, that refers me to the Categories table. phpMyAdmin still runs the query properly while PHP fails. I don't know what to do at this point. I can't update phpMyAdmin though because it is a friend's server, not mine, and it is not dedicated so I don't think he can update it himself anyway. It seems like pMA is not making errors though, it is PHP getting no data...

Comment: @LoganSerman this: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Items i, Categories c WHERE i.category_id = '17' AND i.category_id = c.category_id");` ?

Comment: give the whole query (not the simplified) you use for debug

Comment: That is the whole query I am using for the debug. Just a simple SELECT, nothing more. My code is copy pasted into the OP.

Comment: ok, when you execute `SELECT * FROM Items` and do `var_dump($r)` in the while loop what does it say under category_id for array with item_id of 1 ?

Comment: 12, as mentioned earlier in this thread. In the database it shows as 17. PHP gets 12. phpMyAdmin apparently gets 17 as well. When I use `INSERT` to insert item 1, I inserted with 17.

Comment: do this from your php script `update Items set category_id = 17` when you run it check the db from phpmyadmin. do all items belong to category_id 17 ?

Comment: You did the `insert` using phpMyAdmin? You also don't have to update the existing phpMyAdmin. Just place a current one somewhere in your document root. phpMyAdmin is still just a PHP script.

Comment: They did not all change to 17. Got scared that I was using the wrong DB after checking 100 times so I checked again. I was using the right DB and everything seemed fine. Freaked out and logged out of everything and closed my browser, relogged into phpMyAdmin, and everything was 17, and the script works perfectly. I don't know what happened but it was something weird and it is fixed now. I am not sure what fixed it. I did not change any of my code or connections, I just relogged into phpMyAdmin. Anyone know what happened?

Comment: phpMyAdmin outdated and buggy. /lastbet

Comment: You could use some alternative like http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net if you are unsure about the correctness of your results.

Answer (score 1):

Smells like your script and phpmyadmin are not using the same database. Double check if you have production/development databases.

And double check you're running the script you think you're running, put `die('im here');` before the query line.

Comment: They are using the same database!

Comment: Do the `die` test before. End the script execution right after the while block with die also, to eliminate looking the wrong results to begin with. Use `var_dump($r)` rather than `echo`. It really seems like a silly problem like that.

Comment: It is more than that, sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Items i, Categories c WHERE i.category_id = '17' AND i.category_id = c.category_id");
```

Comment: Good thinking, but this still does not work... PHP is still believing that `Items`.`category_id` is referencing the `parent_id` of the Categories table. Is it something to do with the KEY? When creating the table, `FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Categories (category_id)` was used...

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE Categories`

Comment: Done. When defining FOREIGN KEY in MySQL, does it reference the `KEY` of the referenced table? That seems to be what is going on...

Comment: Do a use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA;

select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'Categories';`

Comment: MyISAM does not support foreign key constraints, so I won't bet on this. Maybe phpMyAdmin tries something that it shouldnt.

Comment: Hm- is there a way to change MyISAM to something that does support foreign key constraints? This is part of a large project and one of the requirements is to have those constraints (which is why we made the tables like we did).